# Perform aggregation in Elasticsearch index with Spark in Java

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to prepare a Java class that will read an index from Elasticsearch, perform aggregations using Spark and then write the results back to Elasticsearch. The target schema (in the form of StructType) is the same as the source one. My code is as follows

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Aggregation").setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
JavaPairRDD<String, Map<String, Object>> pairRDD = JavaEsSpark.esRDD(sc, "kpi_aggregator/record");
RDD rdd = JavaPairRDD.toRDD(pairRDD);
Dataset df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, customSchema);
df.registerTempTable("data");
Dataset kpi1 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT host, SUM(bytes_uplink), SUM(bytes_downlink) FROM data GROUP BY host");
JavaEsSparkSQL.saveToEs(kpi1, "kpi_aggregator_total/record");
```

I am using the latest version of *spark-core_2.11* and *elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11*. The previous code results in the following exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.Tuple2 cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this exception because `sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, customSchema)` expects `RDD<CustomSchemaJavaBean>` but instead you pass to it results of `JavaPairRDD.toRDD(pairRDD)` which is `RDD<Tuple2<String, Map<String, Object>>>`. You have to map your `JavaPairRDD<String, Map<String, Object>>` to `RDD<CustomSchemaJavaBean>`:

```java
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Aggregation").setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
JavaRDD<CustomSchemaBean> rdd = JavaEsSpark.esRDD(sc, "kpi_aggregator/record")
    .map(tuple2 -> { 
        /**transform Tuple2<String, Map<String, Object>> to CustomSchemaBean **/
        return new CustomSchemaBean(????);
    } );
Dataset df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, customSchema);
df.registerTempTable("data");
Dataset kpi1 = sqlContext.sql("SELECT host, SUM(bytes_uplink), SUM(bytes_downlink) FROM data GROUP BY host");
JavaEsSparkSQL.saveToEs(kpi1, "kpi_aggregator_total/record");
```

Notice I used JavaRDD not RDD both methods are [legal](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html#createDataFrame(org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD,%20java.lang.Class)).

Comment: I can't find the information inside JavaRDD<Map<String, Object>>. Assuming that I dave filled this with index data, javardd.collect().size() returns the correct number of rows that exist in the index. But when I print the contents of each map I get empty objects. So where is the data stored inside JavaRDD?

Comment: Can you output Tuple2<String, Map<String, Object>>  tupple = JavaEsSpark.esRDD(sc, "kpi_aggregator/record").first(); System.out.println(tuple2); Does it have any content?

Comment: It prints AVeHa7xHQTp8jnTmbpuf,{}. I guess this is the empty map I saw before. The data appears correctly in the index, GET kpi_aggregator/record/_search?size=1 does return a record correctly.

Comment: Well {} means empty map, so JavaEsSpark don't fill it with the data for some reason, at the same time it returns AVeHa7xHQTp8jnTmbpuf which I guess is a document id, this is weird, can you query ES using GET by a key - AVeHa7xHQTp8jnTmbpuf, does it returns a proper document with it fields filled?

Comment: Ok I figured what the problem was. I needed to enable _source in order to get the data back. Thank you for your help!